# Concerns regarding documentation of libraries in java

Tags: java

I was asked in class to look for libraries along with their operation and documentation type. This is the first time I'm hearing or having anything to do with library documentation. I tried looking for some form of clear and concise explanation of what it is but I don't think I've actually understood what it is and its importance.
Can someone explain to me what is meant by documentation type and where can I find more details of a particular library's documentation?

Comment: What about Java documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: Yes,while looking for details about various libraries I've across this page. While this gives a lot of description about the libraries I didn't really get what portion of all that info actually covered anything about documentation. There is also so much information about each library that I don't know what I should focus on specifically.

Comment: @Hades the JavaDoc link above gives specific, lowlevel api detail for every Class and every method on each class. This is one type of documentation, another example would be the Java platform documentation which is broader and higher level https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/

Comment: For a general definition of documentation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_documentation

Answer (score 1):

Documentation has all the information you need to make use of the library. There are `code samples`, `tutorials`, `developer guides`, `API documentation`, and more to quickly understand the library and use it.
Actually `API documentation` is mostly developers look while using particular library.
It has technical content deliverable, containing instructions about how to effectively use and integrate with an API. It’s a concise reference manual contains all the information required to work with the API, with details about the functions, classes, return types, arguments and more, supported by tutorials and examples.
If you talk about JAVA 7 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ is the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Java APIs are most often documented with JavaDoc. Whether it is generated and shared online or with the library varies from library to library. Other types could be wiki pages, web pages, or other text docs, manuals, reference materials. Pick a couple of popular libraries and then look for their docs. What did you find?